# problem disposing class in Dictionary it is Still in the heap memory although using GC.Collect

Tags: c#

i have a problem  disposing class in Dictionary

this is my code

```
  private Dictionary<string, MyProcessor> Processors = new Dictionary<string, MyProcessor>();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Processors.ContainsKey(textBox1.Text))
            {
                Processors.Add(textBox1.Text, new MyProcessor());
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyProcessor currnt_processor = Processors[textBox2.Text];
            Processors.Remove(textBox2.Text);
            currnt_processor.Dispose();
            currnt_processor = null;
           GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        }








  public class MyProcessor: IDisposable
    {

       private bool isDisposed = false;

       string x = "";

        public MyProcessor()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
            {
            //this line only to increase the memory usage to know if the class is dispose or not
                x = x + "gggggggggggg";    

            }

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            x=null;
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
        }

        public   void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.isDisposed)
            {
                isDisposed = true;
                this.Dispose();
            }
        }

        ~MyProcessor()      
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }


    }
```

i use "ANTS Memory Profiler"  to monitor heap memory

the disposing work only when i remove all keys from dictionary

how can i destroy the class from heap memory ?

this a video link for the problem

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePorlksv2QY

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you calling `this.Dispose` in the constructor??

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. What does the dispose have to do with it? Can you explain why you think having a dispose method makes any difference to *memory* management? Are you under the incorrect belief that dispose is for managing memory?

Comment: this a video link for the problem

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePorlksv2QY

Answer (score 5):

I think you are seeing ghosts - keep in mind that the .NET garbage collection is a generational garbage collection based on memory pressure. If there is no memory pressure your resources will not be garbage collected. Also calling `GC.Collect()` is just a bad idea, I hope you are only doing this for your profiling tests.

As an aside what resources exactly are your disposing in your `Dispose` method? Doesn't look like you need one.

In the implementation you provided not a single `Dispose()` method call nor the finalizer `~MyProcessor()` is needed at all.

Comment: hhhhhhh   this a video link for that ghosts 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePorlksv2QY

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to call a GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(); as GC.Collect(); just kicks off the GC.

It is possible to have a reference leak (ie you inadvertently keep a whole load of references to objects in a list somewhere, preventing their collection). I doubt that the dictionary has such a "leak" as it is such a widely used class that it would be a known problem. Most likely if you have problems with your code most likely the problem is somewhere else in your code.

If this is not causing you actual problems, lay off it, grab your towel and don't panic, the GC does work :)

Comment: not work  this a video link for the problem

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePorlksv2QY

Comment: If you have a real problem it is likely somewhere else in your code. If you don't have a real problem and are just trying to test GC then good luck with that. The GC works.

Comment: i have areal problem not for test ,i know that GC is work but my be there is a problem with Dictionary or some thing i do not know it

Comment: Like I said - I would spend my time first looking at the other code in your app. If you think you have a dictionary that is holding references, after you remove the items from the dictionary copy it to a brand new dictionary then release the reference to your old dictionary. That should help you rule out the dictionary as the problem, then you can go chase the real problem, which is likely somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are removing item with one name but disposing item with another name from dictionary. So item that disposed is still referenced from dictionary (Processors.Remove(textBox2.Text); while current = dict[textBox1.Text]).

Take a note of Eric's comment - Dispose does not make object ready for garbage collection, if it has references it still will be in the memory.